# How to call superuser command from script without sudo

Tags: bash, apache, superuser

I need to call `postfix reload` from a script accessible from php webpage. `postfix reload` requires superuser privileges. I can do it using `echo "password" | sudo ...` But I don't want to give superuser privileges to a script accesible from an apache, nor to write the password there in a  plaintext. How do you call such command without creating security problem? How can software like the ISPConfig solve this need?

Comment: You can configure `sudo` to allow whatever user `apache` runs as to run a *specific* command without a password. How to do so is a bit off-topic for Stack Overflow; try superuser.com.

Comment: My advice would be to decouple the web service from the service reload task. 1001 different ways to do it, at the same time, I would not implement a direct action/reaction of a priviledged command from my production web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user under which Apache is running (ex. apache) must be allowed to execute "sudo postfix reload" without a password. To do that you need to add the 
following line in the '/etc/sudoers' file:

```
apache   ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/postfix reload
```

I recommend in the script to use 'sudo /path/to/postfix reload' since the postfix file  might not be in the default path of apache user.

Regarding security, you need to make sure that this command will not be launched to often since it might cause performance issues. 
Since the command has specified an argument the even if your site would be compromised, the postfix reload will only perform a specific action without possibility to alter that behavior (as long sudo and postfix are up2date).